# What does the lowercase gamma symbol represent in maths?

Tags: probability

Example question:

Suppose...An individual's wealth = £35,000 and he faces a gamble:

Loss of £10,000 with probability of 0.1
No loss probability 0.9

If the person wants to buy insurance of £1,000 and pay £(gamma)thousand - what does this mean?

Comment: The multiple amount of thousand

Comment: $\gamma$ means nothing special.

Comment: In this context at least, $\gamma$ means nothing special. Also you can write `$\gamma$` for the symbol.

Comment: The amount paid for insurance is usually called the *insurance premium*

Comment: It's just a variable, standing in for an unknown number of thousands of pounds. Your goal in this problem is to set up an equation for $\gamma$, and solve that equation for $\gamma$.